# send email from sql server express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, email, triggers, sql-server-express

i want to send an email as a user inserts some data into a table. is this possible in sql express? please help with the code.

i would use a trigger for insertion on the table. 
for email what features shall i have on my PC. i have Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SQL Express does not support the Database Mail feature, so this would not be possible out of the box. As per the note at the bottom of the [Database Mail MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) article for Sql Server 2008 R2:

> Database Mail is not available in SQL
>   Server Express.

A more robust solution would be to embed the notification logic in the application tier (e.g C#) which talks to the database.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I didn't find any deprecation against enabling SQL CLR onto SQL Server Express,

you can try to use SQL CLR Trigger with `System.Net.Mail` objects.

Comment: can you help me out with the complete code?

Comment: sp_OACreate - does this also won't help me out?

Comment: @sqlchild: [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sql+clr+email) I found [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1795)

Comment: @sqlchild: SQL CLR is pretty complex topic, can't fit into a single comment

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with SQL Express. If you happen to update to the full management studio you would use msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail to send your email.

Comment: you mean there's no way sending email via sql express

Comment: "update to the full management studio" --what does this mean? you mean to say that updating to sql server by buying it?

Comment: database mail is not built into sql express. management studio is basically the full version and has database mail functionality. as far as what email client you would need, it depends on your type of email. for something like gmail anything that handled smtp should be fine. if youre running on exchange you'd need a mapi client like outlook (also not the express version)

Comment: please tell me, i am confused about management studio and sql server. according to me management studio is just an interface for operating sql server? am i right? so if i have sql server express & have installed sql management studio express then can i use database mail? also, are management studio and management studio express different?

Comment: im speaking incorrectly then. if you have server express it doesnt have dbmail available. non-express sql server is where the dbmail is turned on among other things. so yes, you are right that management studio is just the GUI. There are more features in the non-express management studio as well.